# Finding "hidden patterns" in string in MSSQL data using regex (Positive Lookahead)

Tags: sql-server, wildcard

I'm working on finding obfuscated data in string fields. I have a regex that works in a Python script, but I realized that what I was doing would likely be done more efficiently directly in the database. BUT MSSQL doesn't support lookaround (Positive Lookahead.)

Eventually I want to dynamically feed an sql statement a list of targets to search for in candidates, but for now I am just trying to figure out how to get the match working.

**Target:**

1. "4X5G"

**Candidates:**

1. "Ipsum 47 loreix 5-g blue scuba rock." 4X5G are 13 characters apart, I would want to return this a potential candidate.
2. "Ipsum 47 loreix blue scuba 5-g rock." 4X5G are 24 characters apart, I would NOT want to return this a potential candidate.

Traditional REGEX:

```
(?=.{9,14}g)4.*?x.*?5.*?g
```

What DOESN'T work:

```
WHERE [field] LIKE '%(?=.{9,14}g)4.*?x.*?5.*?g%'
```

Comment: If you need proper regular expression support you need to use CLR. The `LIKE` syntax is simple wildcards, not regex

Comment: More, MSSQL does not support regex, only wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I like this implementation: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6529/sql-server-regex-clr-function/

Answer (score 0):

By using the information here: [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6529/sql-server-regex-clr-function/) I was able to add a CLR and create a scalar function in my database that works great. I can feed it complicated regex statements and get back results.

Thanks!